# Linq-to-SQL - multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, multiple-tables

Really basic LINQ question but can someone enlighten me as to how it handles data when it's taken from multiple database tables.

For example if you have a `Products` tables then using the DBML you get a nice `Product` object which you can query, update, create etc. (`Product.Name`, `Product.Price` etc.) All very nice.

However, if I have a LINQ query that joins `Product` on a bunch of other tables and brings me back the columns from those tables. There's no 1:1 mapping of DB table to object possible so what is it returned as?

Eg. If it was a combo of `Product` and `Customer` how would I query, for example, the customer name:

```
object.customerName ?
```

Is it returned as a dataset by default?

Comment: not clear on what you are expecting?

Comment: It's theoretical at this stage so don't have a query to show. Imagine a simple LINQ to SQL join though, the result of that join is what? Is it a dataset? Datatable?

Comment: I highly recommend LinqPad for testing and developing LINQ queries: http://www.linqpad.net/.  The website has some great tutorials too, as does Microsoft's Linq 101 sample site: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Will check out Linq pad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would generally (that's: often, but not always.) compose anonymous types which your query will return a collection of. You name the properties, say, and can then access them as you would with any other type.

Comment: Ah...ok. I figured it might be something like a custom class....but anonymous types sounds interesting. Not sure I've used them before. Am I right in thinking that if I created a custom class then I'll need properties for all returned values I want access to? Even as I type that I know it's the case....but just making sure!

Comment: Thanks, that's the info I was looking for. Must read more about anonymous types. In your experience would you opt for them over a custom class? Which are faster to create?

Comment: Anonymous classes are very good for shaping data and working with it in LINQ.  The only time I would use a custom class is if I need to return shaped data from a method and use it in other places, in which case I need a return type like `List<MyCustomClass>`.

Comment: +1 Just remember they are only usefull for readonly actions. If you want to update, you need to return the entities themselves

Answer (score 1):

It creates what's called an 'anonymous type'.  You can use it like this:

```
var x = from p in context.Products
        join o in OrderLines in p.Id = o.ItemId
        select new    // you are creating your anonymous type here
        {
            OrderId = o.Id,
            ProductName = p.Name,
            OrderDate = o.Date
        }

foreach (var y in x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Product name: " + y.ProductName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your keys are set up properly, you should be able to do queries like Product.Customers or the other way around. Or you can join two tables, the syntax is similar to this:

```
from p in context.Products
join c in context.Customers on p.CId equals c.Id
```

Comment: Ok, and what would the result be exactly? I mean if I just queried the product table and return a product object that's fine. But what kind of object am I getting back if I join a few tables and the result is an amalgamation of a few tables?

Comment: The return type depends on you. You can send anonymous type with new {} or any custom type you want. No need to give -ve for this thing.

Answer (score 0):

You would generally have anonymous type or custom object depending upon the select clause of your query

```
from p in context.Products
join //with other tables with appropriate join conditions
select new
{
   prop1 = p.ProductName,
   prop2 = p.ProductId
}
```

This would return an anonymous type with 2 properties prop1 & prop2

```
from p in context.Products
join //with other tables with appropriate join conditions
select new MyProduct()
{
   prop1 = p.ProductName,
   prop2 = p.ProductId
}
```

This would return custom object called MyProduct & you can set its properties in object initializer's block

Answer (score 0):

You can create a View in the database and through Linq-to-SQL you can map to an Object.